# Anonymous users taking CM license spots

Tags: content-management, licensing

I have a scenario with Sitecore 9.2 where CM users are getting the "too many users" message when they try to log in. I've gone in there as a global admin to kick users (since regular users can't), and I've found the slots are taken up by sitecore\anonymous users. I believe the client does browse the site on the CM sometimes, but that would be against the web database, and there's no end-user login on this site. So it seems very odd that an anonymous account can eat a CM login slot. Has anyone encountered this and have a solution? (I do have a Sitecore ticket on this as well, if they come back with a solution I'll provide it to everyone.)

Comment: Any background jobs running at that time?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I'm not 100% sure if something's running at the specific time, but there's a custom agent that runs every three hours to do CRUD operations on content from an external source.

Comment: You may want to check if it's not related

Comment: What is domain value in site definition for the website?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat It's "extranet" in the site definition

Comment: @KenMcAndrew have you received any answer from Sitecore Support?

Comment: @MarekMusielak Yes, it's a bug, you can check with them for a hotfix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the issue on my Sitecore 9.3 instance.
And when I access the KickUser admin page (https://Your_Instance_url/sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/KickUser), this is what I can see:

[image: Kick off user screenshot]

It appears the Kick Off user page is wrongly showing the logged in users as Sitecore\Anonymous - which could be an issue we can follow up with Sitecore. In my case, I have two valid Sitecore users logged in (and not Anonymous users)

So basically what you are seeing as Anonymous users are actually valid CMS users. Please verify.

**Update**
Sitecore have confirmed this is a bug and provided the reference number **364166**. More information about public reference numbers [can be found here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll pass this on to Sitecore as well. It makes more sense, though it's annoying that it's showing the wrong information.

Comment: Sitecore was able to reproduce this on 9.2 and has assigned bug ID 364166 to it. As I hear more about a fix, I'll update this entry as well.

Comment: Hi @KenMcAndrew just checking if you are happy to mark the provided answer as acceptable? Also we have the Sitecore KB Id, we can include it in the original question or the acceptable answer above?